# Issues with lxml in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

Having some issues with lxml.  I'm trying to run a script in Atom and kept getting an error stating "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml'"  couldn't figure out what was going on as I had installed the module, and when running from the command prompt to test in python: "import lxml" worked just fine... tried it with python3: "import lxml" and get No module named lxml.  Is it a path issue?  Where is the difference between the two?  Any help is appreciated.

[lxml works in python but not python3 (screen cap)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfeIS.png)

EDIT: Found a difference in the PYTHONPATH, how do I fix the sys.path for Python3?
[Path difference between python and python3 (screen Cap)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8R0w.png)

Comment: Sounds like you have lxml installed for Python2, but not Python3.  Try `pip3 install lxml`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! There is a better chance that you will get a high quality answer if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please do not share code or the expected output as pictures.